# Hiding empty values and Linking values

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am using a WordPress site and wanted to integrate photo captions and photo credit line under the fatured image. I found a great code that adds a Photographer credit and URL field to the media upload page. However, upon displaying it in the page, I want to further customize it.

Currently, when i upload a photo, i can add a photographer name, and a photographer (or source) URL. The URL automatically links to the name if filled in. However, what I want to do is add a text and icon before the photographer name to say "(icon) Image Credit / "

I was able to add it using css, however, when there is no photographer name, it still shows the Image Credit text and icon but no name. How can I hide that when there is no value in the photographer name field?

also, if i enter a photographer name, but no URL, it links the name to an empty URL. How can i make it so that it does not link the name if the URL field is empty?

Here is the code i am working with:

```
function be_attachment_field_credit( $form_fields, $post ) {
$form_fields['be-photographer-name'] = array(
    'label' => 'Photographer Name',
    'input' => 'text',
    'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'be_photographer_name', true ),
    'helps' => 'If provided, photo credit will be displayed',
);

$form_fields['be-photographer-url'] = array(
    'label' => 'Photographer URL',
    'input' => 'text',
    'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'be_photographer_url', true ),
    'helps' => 'Add Photographer URL',
);

return $form_fields;
}

add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'be_attachment_field_credit', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Save values of Photographer Name and URL in media uploader
 *
 * @param $post array, the post data for database
 * @param $attachment array, attachment fields from $_POST form
 * @return $post array, modified post data
 */

function be_attachment_field_credit_save( $post, $attachment ) {
    if( isset( $attachment['be-photographer-name'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post['ID'], 'be_photographer_name', $attachment['be-photographer-name'] );

    if( isset( $attachment['be-photographer-url'] ) )
update_post_meta( $post['ID'], 'be_photographer_url', esc_url( $attachment['be-photographer-url'] ) );

    return $post;
}

add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_save', 'be_attachment_field_credit_save', 10, 2 );
```

Then in my single.php file I added the following code to display the photo credit.

```
<div id="tgg_credit_line" class="tgg-photo-credit" align="right">
  <?php echo "&#x1F4F7; Image Credit / " ?><a href="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'be_photographer_url', true); ?>"><?php echo get_post_meta(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'be_photographer_name', true); ?></a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first check to see if there is a photographer name set, and if not, don't add any of the credit code. You can also check whether there is a url and then only add the link tag when necessary. This code should be used in place of what you have in the single templates.

```
<?php 
$photographer_name = get_post_meta(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'be_photographer_name', true);
$photographer_url = get_post_meta(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'be_photographer_url', true);

if ( $photographer_name ) : ?>
    <div id="tgg_credit_line" class="tgg-photo-credit" align="right">
    &#x1F4F7; Image Credit /
    <?php if ( $photographer_url ) : ?> 
         <a href="<?php echo $photographer_url ?>">
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php echo $photographer_name ?>
    <?php if ( $photographer_url ) : ?> 
         </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This works great for hiding the Image Credit text, however, it is still showing an empty link on the photographer name when the URL field is empty and now, even if i put a url in the URL field, it does not link it.

Comment: I see that there are missing $ in front of the photographer_name variables in the if statements and there was a misspelled phot`a`grapher in there...

Comment: It does. If you don't mind, i have another question. How would I implement this code to work with a gallery post format

Comment: I'm not sure. If you're just using the built in WordPress gallery I'd look around online or in the code to see if there are any hooks. If you find something and get a start and link to the new question in this comment thread I'll check it out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48535908/customizing-wordpress-gallery-post-format