# Customizing WordPress Gallery Post Format

Tags: php, wordpress, gallery, post-format

My current theme supports Gallery Post Formats. The Gallery format takes all images from the gallery and displays them in a slideshow. I want to be able to add the caption and photo credit line to the bottom of each image as it changes for the information to change along with it.

The current gallery format template looks like this:

```
 <?php if ( has_post_format( 'gallery' ) ) : ?>

   <div class="gallery-post-format">
      <?php
      $galleries = get_post_gallery_images( $post );

      $output = '<ul class="gallery-images">';
      foreach ($galleries as $gallery) {
         $output .= '<li>' . '<img src="'. $gallery . '">' . '</li>';
      }
      $output .= '</ul>';

      echo $output;
      ?>
   </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I am wanting to add the following code to display the captions and photo credit line to each image.

```
    <div>
    <?php 
        $photographer_name = get_post_meta(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'be_photographer_name', true);
        $photographer_url = get_post_meta(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'be_photographer_url', true);

        if ( $photographer_name ) : ?>
            <div id="tgg_credit_line" class="tgg-photo-credit" align="right">
                &#x1F4F7; Image Credit /
                <?php if ( $photographer_url ) : ?> 
                <a href="<?php echo $photographer_url ?>">
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php echo $photographer_name ?>
                <?php if ( $photographer_url ) : ?> 
                </a>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<div id="tgg_image_caption" class="tgg-image-caption" align="left">
    <?php echo get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt; ?>
</div>

</div>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
<?php if ( has_post_format( 'gallery' ) ) : ?>

    <div class="gallery-post-format">
        <?php
            $gallery = get_post_gallery( $post, false );
            $att_ids = wp_parse_id_list( $gallery['ids'] );

            $output = '<ul class="gallery-images">';
            for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $gallery['src'] ); $i++ ) {
                $att_id = $att_ids[ $i ];
                $photographer_name = get_post_meta( $att_id, 'be_photographer_name', true );
                $photographer_url = get_post_meta( $att_id, 'be_photographer_url', true );

                $image = sprintf( '<img src="%s" />',
                    esc_url( $gallery['src'][ $i ] ) );

                $caption = '<div>';
                if ( $photographer_name ) {
                    $caption .= '<div class="tgg-photo-credit" align="right">';
                    $caption .= '&#x1F4F7; Image Credit /';
                    if ( $photographer_url ) {
                        $caption .= sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>',
                            esc_url( $photographer_url ), esc_html( $photographer_name ) );
                    } else {
                        $caption .= esc_html( $photographer_name );
                    }
                    $caption .= '</div><!-- .tgg-photo-credit -->';
                }
                $caption .= '</div>';

                $excerpt = get_post_field( 'post_excerpt', $att_id );
                if ( $excerpt ) {
                    $caption .= /* wrapped */
                    '<div class="tgg-image-caption" align="left">' .
                        $excerpt .
                    '</div><!-- .tgg-image-caption -->';
                }

                $output .= '<li>' . $image . $caption . '</li>';
            }
            $output .= '</ul><!-- .gallery-images -->';

            echo $output;
        ?>
    </div><!-- gallery-post-format -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Or another version, which directly `echo`es the output instead of saving it in a variable (i.e. `$output`):

```
<?php if ( has_post_format( 'gallery' ) ) : ?>

    <div class="gallery-post-format">
        <?php
            $gallery = get_post_gallery( $post, false );
            $att_ids = wp_parse_id_list( $gallery['ids'] );
        ?>
        <ul class="gallery-images">
            <?php for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $gallery['src'] ); $i++ ) : ?>
                <li>
                    <?php
                        $att_id = $att_ids[ $i ];
                        $photographer_name = get_post_meta( $att_id, 'be_photographer_name', true );
                        $photographer_url = get_post_meta( $att_id, 'be_photographer_url', true );
                        $excerpt = get_post_field( 'post_excerpt', $att_id );
                    ?>

                    <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $gallery['src'][ $i ] ); ?>" />

                    <div>
                        <?php if ( $photographer_name ) : ?>
                            <div class="tgg-photo-credit" align="right">
                                &#x1F4F7; Image Credit /
                                <?php if ( $photographer_url ) : ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $photographer_url ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $photographer_name ); ?></a>
                                <?php else : ?>
                                    <?php echo esc_html( $photographer_name ); ?>
                                <?php endif; // end $photographer_url ?>
                            </div><!-- .tgg-photo-credit -->
                        <?php endif; // end $photographer_name ?>
                    </div>

                    <?php if ( $excerpt ) : ?>
                        <div class="tgg-image-caption" align="left">
                            <?php echo $excerpt; ?>
                        </div><!-- .tgg-image-caption -->
                    <?php endif; // end $excerpt ?>
                </li>
            <?php endfor; // end gallery loop ?>
        </ul><!-- .gallery-images -->
    </div><!-- .gallery-post-format -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @sally. How do I get the &#x1F4F7; Image Credit / to display in front of the photographer name? Also, how can I get the photographer name aligned to the right and the caption aligned to the left?

Comment: another thing I just realized, When using the gallery post format, it creates a slideshow separate from the featured image. so i dont want the featured image to appear on single posts, but i still need to attach it to the post so that it shows up as thumbnails on the home page. How can I do that using this code?

Comment: I've updated the code. Try it out (the first or second version) and let me know.

Comment: In reply to your second comment, I think it involves modifying the `single.php` template. Can you share the template content/code on [Pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/) and share its URL? Or if you don't mind, just let me know me the name of theme you're actually using. (Or name of the parent theme, if you're using a child theme.)

Comment: I am using a custom child theme for colormag

Comment: Regarding the other thing, I can't edit my comment because the thumbnail thing wasn't part of your original question. However, I'm more than happy to help you with that. It's pretty simple, actually. But can you share (again, on Pastebin.com) the `content-single.php` file of the custom child theme? The reason is, because you might have added custom code snippets in that file and I can't simply modify the default one in the parent theme and share the file.

Comment: Thanks. Here it is: [https://pastebin.com/kCpL3kVi](https://pastebin.com/kCpL3kVi). (I commented out and not removed the lines, so that you could easily enable it back if you want/need.)

Comment: Not working. When I add the featured image to the post, it still shows the featured image in the single post and now it also shows the featured image and the gallery in thumbnails on the home page. But if I remove the featured image from the post it will not show the featured image or the gallery in the thumbnails of the home page.

Comment: Well then, how about this, where we remove the entire `.featured-image` DIV: [https://pastebin.com/NFrW8cca](https://pastebin.com/NFrW8cca)

Comment: That works!!! Thanks so much! Im pretty new to SO, is there a way i can add you as a friend?

Comment: I spoke too soon. That code also disables showing the featured image on regular posts as well.

Comment: Try this, which disables the `.featured-image` DIV only on single posts with the "gallery" format: [https://pastebin.com/cu92A2VF](https://pastebin.com/cu92A2VF)

Comment: THATS IT! Thanks!check it out! www.michigancityjournal.com

Comment: It's my pleasure, and I like your site! =)